# What is evcent() returning for directed graphs?

Tags: r, igraph

if you write

```
evcent(g, directed = TRUE)
```

where g is a directed graph you get a warning  At centrality.c:353 :Weighted directed graph in eigenvector centrality.

It is my understanding that for a directed network you can calculate `in-eigenvector centrality` and `out-eigenvector centrality`

In `mathematica` you can specify in or out. But what is `evcent()` from `igraph` calculating? 
I can't figure out how it deals with directed graphs and `?evcent` simply says it's the `centrality scores`

Comment: In igraph "in" is calculated. I guess, you get a warning because the solution might be complex, depending on your weights.